# Can I combine two different DOM to combine selector :nth-child with combined indexes?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Supposed I have these kind of html

```
<div class="one">
   <span>1</span>
   <span>2</span>
   <span>3</span>
</div>
<div class="two">
   <span>4</span>
   <span>5</span>
   <span>6</span>
</div>
```

The css code is below

```
span:nth-child(2),
span:nth-child(4),
span:nth-child(6){
   background-color:red;
}
```

This is what I want by using css above

```
<div class="one">
   <span>1</span>
   <span>2</span> <!--Become red-->
   <span>3</span>
</div>
<div class="two">
   <span>4</span> <!--Become red-->
   <span>5</span>
   <span>6</span> <!--Become red-->
</div>
```

Can I combine div with class "one" and "two", then use nth-child with combined indexes between those two classes?

Comment: No, you just can't.

Comment: Nope, the reason is because CSS cannot traverse up the DOM node tree (at least for now). You will have to rely on JS for that.

Comment: "Can I combine div with class 'one' and 'two', then use nth-child with combined indexes between those two classes?" No because the children of .one are not children of .two and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define different selectors for spans in `div.one` and in `div.two` to achieve this.

Like this:

```
.one span:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

And

```
.two span:nth-child(1), .two span:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: red;
}
```